# Here the output prints the address. How can I print the course names as output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

in the following code Teacher class takes all variables as private and Course class takes public variabes.

```
class Teacher:
  def __init__(self,name,department='CSE'):
    self.__department= department
    self.__name = name
    
  def printDetail(self):
    print('Name:',self.__name)
    print('Department:',self.__department)
    print('List of courses')
   
    print(self.x) 

  def addCourse(self,x):  
    self.x = x

class Course:
  def __init__(self,course):
    self.course = course
  
t1 = Teacher("Saad Abdullah", "CSE")
c1 = Course("CSE 110 Programming Language I")
c2 = Course("CSE 111 Programming Language-II")
t1.addCourse(c1)   
t1.addCourse(c2)
t1.printDetail()
```

how do define addCourse and print it in details?
the output should be

```
Name: Saad Abdullah
Department: CSE
List of courses

CSE 110 Programming Language I
CSE 111 Programming Language-II
```

Comment: You can try to add a list attribute and add the courses to it in `addCourse`. Then print this list in the `printDetail` method. Try that and come ask here when that goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does exactly what you need.

```py
class Teacher:
  def __init__(self,name,department='CSE'):
    self.__department= department
    self.__name = name
    self.__courses = []
    
  def printDetail(self):
    print('Name: ', self.__name)
    print('Department: ', self.__department)
    print('List of courses:')
    print()
    for course in self.__courses:
      print(course)

  def addCourse(self, x):  
    self.__courses.append(x)

class Course:
  def __init__(self,course):
    self.course = course

  # show how class should be printed
  def __str__(self):
    return self.course  
  
t1 = Teacher("Saad Abdullah", "CSE")
c1 = Course("CSE 110 Programming Language I")
c2 = Course("CSE 111 Programming Language-II")
t1.addCourse(c1)   
t1.addCourse(c2)
t1.printDetail()
```